# How to use repetition in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, repeat

I am trying to get this code to keep repeating once the final line is displayed, and repeat as many times as you want, then display a termination message once a certain number is entered for account number. What would be the best way to do this? I have been struggling trying to get an if statement to work out, maybe someone has the solution.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{ //begin main
  int AccountNumber; //declare account number

  int BeginingBalance; //declare begining balance

  int TotalItemsCharged; //declare total items charged

  int TotalCreditsApplied; //declare total credits applied

  int CreditLimit; //declare credit limit

  Double Balance; //declare end balance

  {
     Console.Write("account number: "); // prompt user for account number
     AccountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     Console.Write("begining balance: "); //prompt user for begining balance
     BeginingBalance = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     Console.Write("total items charged: ");
     TotalItemsCharged = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //prompt user for items charged

     Console.Write("total credits applied:");
     TotalCreditsApplied = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //prompt user for credits applied

     Console.Write("credit limit:"); //prompt user for credit limit
     CreditLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     Balance = BeginingBalance + TotalItemsCharged - TotalCreditsApplied;

     Console.Write("balance is: {0}", Balance); //display calculated balance

     if (Balance > CreditLimit) //set if statement
        Console.WriteLine(" Credit Limit Exceeded"); //set display for true if statement

     Console.ReadLine();
      } // end main
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you familiarized yourself with the `while` loop?

Comment: Please get a good C# book, this is a really very basic question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Comment: What about `while (true)`? That will definitely repeat... :)

Comment: I'm guessing the inner most brackets is what you would like to repeat, in pretty much all programming this is known as a loop. You should be able to look on your favourite search engine for a multitude of resources about looping

Comment: Your teacher did not explain about loops at all ? And you are totally unfamiliar with google ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Keep asking for an account number until 0 is entered as account number
while ((AccountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())) != 0)
{
    // No need to ask for the account number again, the while loop takes care
    // of that.

    // So...
    // do stuff, such as...
    BeginningBalance = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    // and more stuff... etc...
}
```